# Execlp doesn't return a number

Tags: c

I have 2 programs and I need the value of the secound program to continue correctly my first program. I call a secound program with the execlp and save the number of kill in ret, but don't return the number correctly.
Someone I can help?

First application;

```
pid_t pid;
int ret=0;
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){

    ret = execlp("/media/partilha/scomp1516t2dag02/modulo1/ex20/batota", "batota", (char*) NULL);
    if(ret == -1){
        printf("Erro da aplicação!");
        exit(0);
    }
}
wait(&estado);
```

Second Application

```
int main(void){
    int ret;

    srand(time(NULL));
    ret = (rand() % 5) + 1;
    exit(ret);
}
```

Comment: `execlp` **doesn't** return (unless there's an error).

Comment: Do not talk to often in this forum because of my English is not the best, but thanks. When my problem if someone could help me grateful.

Comment: After the `wait`returns, you should be able to get the exit status of the child process using `WEXITSTATUS(estado)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Already is working properly, it lacked the WEXITSTATUS (state). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `execlp` system call doesn't return
unless there is an error.  It will replace your current program with a new one (your code stops there, replaced by the new one).

From the man page for [`execlp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp):

> "The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image"

Maybe you should look into how `fork()` works, it could help you. The `wait()` system call suspends execution of the calling process until one of its children terminates.  Except here, there are no children of your process; use `fork()` to make one.

- [`wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)
- [`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)